# BLE: How do 2 BLE devices w/random MACs know if they're paired?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Suppose you have 2 BLE devices that periodically randomize their MAC addresses for security reasons. But they were paired.  How do these 2 BLE devices w/random MACs know if they're paired when they meet again after being out of range? i.e. What kind of packets are sent back and forth to determine this?

Comment: This sounds like a networking question, not a programming question. Once you understand the protocol, StackOverflow can help with programming questions like what options to use to create certain messages on a BLE interface.

Answer (score 1):

Random addresses are created using a specific algorithm so that only those possessing the Identity Resolving Key, which is distributed during pairing, can verify that a given random address belongs to a given device.

If you want to know the details you should simply read the Security Manager specification in the Bluetooth Core documentation.